# Set Big Image Same As Height Width of image Tag Without Stretch

Tags: html, css, image

I want to try set big image in 160 x 160 height width. but it stretch. i want without stretch. don't want to crop image

```
<img src="Admin/jobimg/<?php echo $logo ?>" style="overflow:hidden;" height="160px" width="160px" alt="img">
```

actual image was very big.

[image: this is stretch image.]

i want image size with 160 x 160

Comment: So set the width only and add it to a block element with overflow hidden

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src="//placehold.it/640x480">
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
img{height:160px;}
.img-wrapper{height:160px; width:160px; overflow:hidden;}
```

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/hglbKqHfRW

Comment: check here and tell me

Answer (score 0):

Set the width or height only and add it to a block element with overflow hidden.

Please note it is NOT SVG so it will become blurry if you scale it too high

1. remove the constraint from image tag on both directions inline or CSS
2. set the allowed constraint in CSS on the image class (width OR height but not both)
3. constrain on the container with overflow:hidden.

```css
.thumb img { height:72px;}
.thumb{
  height:72px;
  width:72px; /* Coin only */
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumb"><img src="http://www.jagranjosh.com/imported/images/E/Current%20Affairs/RBI-logo-report.png" /></div>
```

```css
.thumb img { height:160px;}
.thumb{
  height:160px;
  width:160px; /* Coin only */
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumb"><img src="http://www.jagranjosh.com/imported/images/E/Current%20Affairs/RBI-logo-report.png" /></div>
```

---

***SVG*** I found the logo at wikicommons

```css
img.svg { height:160px;
  width:160px;
  }
```

```html
<img class="svg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Seal_of_the_Reserve_Bank_of_India.svg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a container of your images. It should have a width and height. Then the image under that container will have absolute positioning.

Ex.

```
.image-container{
    position:relative;
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
}

.image-container img{
    position:absolute;
    background-size:cover;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Much better also you use twitter bootstrap for scaling of the images by using `img-responsive` class for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

This will take 160x160 space without stretching the image

```
img{
    width:160px;
    height:160px; 

/*Scale down will take the necessary specified space that is 160px x 160px without stretching the image*/
    object-fit:scale-down;
}
```